# Why is the hexadecimal number, returned by inet_aton, in inverted order?

Tags: c

I want to convert a string of IP address to its corresponding hexadecimal number. The below is the program to do so, but I got the inverted number. For example, if the string is 128.2.194.242, the result is f2c20280. The same thing happens when I tried converting from a string of hexadecimal to IP with inet_ntoa. What is wrong with program?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    struct in_addr in;

    if((inet_aton(argv[1], &in)) == 0)
        error("inet_ntoa");

    printf("hex: %x", in.s_addr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this is wrong?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between host order and network order.

Comment: the host order of bytes and the network order of bytes 'might' be the same.  It depends on the Endian (big or small) of the host machine.

Comment: I also suspected my problem may relate to big endian and small endian, but I am new with this stuff, and I don't know that printf would change the order. Thanks guys anyway

Answer (score 3):

Your host byte order and network byte order do not match. When you call `inet_aton`, the address is stored in memory in network byte order. When you call `printf` with the `%x` format specifier, it prints the same region of memory using host byte order. If you call `ntohl`, which converts a `long` from network to host byte order, before printing the address, you will see the address printed in the "right" order:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    struct in_addr in;

    if((inet_aton(argv[1], &in)) == 0)
        error("inet_ntoa");

    printf("hex: %x", ntohl(in.s_addr));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it sounds like I have to convert two time to get the network byte order with printf, right?